# Android Drawable folder for a specific resolution

Tags: android, resolution

Is it possible to make a drawable folder for a specific screen resolution? For example, I have a phone that is 540 x 960. Can I make a folder something like this?

```
drawable-540x960
```

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I can tell from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

You can define smallest available width, for instance (`sw`) or available width (`w`), but that would also apply to larger devices...